# Кто знает формулу расчета flex-shrink?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Всем привет. Скажите пожалуйста по какой формуле рассчитывается данное свойство? Очень хочу разобраться!

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#layout-algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[здесь все красиво и для таких, как мы](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-flex-shrink-%D0%B2-css-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-c41e40767194)

Comment: Чувствую, статейка весёлая, если учесть, что там такая математика `150 + 200 + 300 - 500 = -150px` ;-)

Comment: @UModel, даже боги ошибаются)

Comment: Спасибо , читал данную статью , но  в комментах написали , что есть ошибки в вычислениях , поэтому решил уточнить здесь))